# Adding View / Controller not working in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, asp.net-core

In the Context Menu I click on add and then I choose View or controller, Then the related Dialog Box for selecting the type of controller ,(or view seetings) shows up. After Selecting what I want the message "Scaffolding..." appears for a second and disapears, but no view or controller is added.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is a ASP.Net Core project? In my VS2015 ASP.Net core project there is no `Add´ > `View`action. I only have this option with "nromal" ASP.Net projects

Comment: @Daniel `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Framework)`

Comment: I cannot see an Add View Option too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to post this as an answer in order to show the images...

1. New project

[image]

2. Web Application

[image]

3. There is no `Add` > `View`

[image]

4. Under `New from Template` i have other dialogs...

[image]

That's why i am assuming that you took the wrong template...

Comment: As I thought that my hosting may not have .Net Core Installed I used `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Framework)` and not `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Core)`, However why should it appear an not work?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani i tried it with `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Framework)` (changed the pictures) but the dialogs are the same. I'm assuming that you have some extension installed that does not handle  .NET Core projects. Have you tried using *yeoman* for templating?

Comment: nope, I haven't. You mus be right, as no one sees these menus then an extension or something might be creating them.